# validate age input to prompt message when enter alphabet, symbol and negative number

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to validate the input age with the code I wrote below

```
cout << "Enter the Age of The " << qty << " Passenger(s) :: ";
for (int i = 1; i <= qty; i++) {
    cout << "\nAge for Passenger " << i << " :: ";
    cin >> age[i];

    while ((!(cin >> age[i])) || (age[i]<=0)) {
        // Explain the error
        cout << "Error: Enter a valid age for Passenger " << i << " : ";
        // Clear the previous input
        cin.clear();
        // Discard previous input
        cin.ignore(123, '\n');
    }
}
```

But, there is a problem. The program will stop running when I enter the age inside the range.
So, I want to ask is there any effective way to validate the age input.

Comment: What does _"The program will stop running when I enter the age inside the range."_ mean?

Comment: You could read the age as string and use a regular expression to validate it.

Comment: like when i enter 50 for my input, the program stopped

Comment: What's the value of `qty`? How is `age` defined? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I'm guessing there's a VLA, like `int age[qty];`, and UB because `i` will reach `qty` and `age[qty]` is out of bounds. chuustagram: Indexing starts at `0` and should end at `qty - 1`

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `std::getline` and `std::stringsstream`. So you are just reading line and then trying to parse it.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int qty = 10;
    int* age = new int[11];
    std::cout << "Enter the Age of The " << qty << " Passenger(s) :: ";
    for (int i = 1; i <= qty; i++) {
        std::cout << "\nAge for Passenger " << i << " :: ";
        std::string s;
        std::getline(std::cin, s);
        std::stringstream stream(s);

        while ((!(stream >> age[i])) || (age[i]<=0)) {
            // Explain the error
            std::cout << "Error: Enter a valid age for Passenger " << i << " : ";
            std::getline(std::cin, s);
            stream = std::stringstream (s);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= qty; i++) {
        std::cout << age[i];
    }

    delete [] age;
    return 0;
}
```

Also note, that it is bad pattern to use `using namespace std` and indexation from 1